# How to Get the file name for record in spark RDD (JavaRDD)

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I am loading multiple files into a JavaRDD using

```
JavaRDD<String> allLines = sc.textFile(hdfs://path/*.csv);
```

After loading the files I modify each record and want to save them. However I need to also save the original file name (ID) with the record for future reference. Is there anyway that I can get the original file name from the individual record in RDD?
thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to do something like in the following snippet:

```
JavaPairRDD<LongWritable, Text> javaPairRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
    "hdfs://path/*.csv", 
    TextInputFormat.class, 
    LongWritable.class, 
    Text.class, 
    new Configuration()
);
JavaNewHadoopRDD<LongWritable, Text> hadoopRDD = (JavaNewHadoopRDD) javaPairRDD;

JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, String>> namedLinesRDD = hadoopRDD.mapPartitionsWithInputSplit((inputSplit, lines) -> {
    FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit) inputSplit;
    String fileName = fileSplit.getPath().getName();

    Stream<Tuple2<String, String>> stream =
        StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(lines, Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
            .map(line -> {
                String lineText = line._2().toString();
                // emit file name as key and line as a value
                return new Tuple2(fileName, lineText);
            });
    return stream.iterator();
}, true);
```

## Update (for java7)

```
JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, String>> namedLinesRDD = hadoopRDD.mapPartitionsWithInputSplit(
    new Function2<InputSplit, Iterator<Tuple2<LongWritable, Text>>, Iterator<Tuple2<String, String>>>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<Tuple2<String, String>> call(InputSplit inputSplit, final Iterator<Tuple2<LongWritable, Text>> lines) throws Exception {
            FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit) inputSplit;
            final String fileName = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
            return new Iterator<Tuple2<String, String>>() {
                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return lines.hasNext();
                }
                @Override
                public Tuple2<String, String> next() {
                    Tuple2<LongWritable, Text> entry = lines.next();
                    return new Tuple2<String, String>(fileName, entry._2().toString());
                }
            };
        }
    }, 
    true
);
```

Comment: Stream doesn't seem to be available in Java 7 :( is there any replacement? thx

Answer (score 4):

You want spark's [wholeTextFiles](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#wholeTextFiles%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) function. From the documentation:

```
For example, if you have the following files:

   hdfs://a-hdfs-path/part-00000
   hdfs://a-hdfs-path/part-00001
   ...
   hdfs://a-hdfs-path/part-nnnnn

Do val rdd = sparkContext.wholeTextFile("hdfs://a-hdfs-path"),

then rdd contains

   (a-hdfs-path/part-00000, its content)
   (a-hdfs-path/part-00001, its content)
   ...
   (a-hdfs-path/part-nnnnn, its content)
```

It returns you an RDD of tuples where the left is the filename and the right is the content.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I could use this however it seems as whole text file doesn't really create RDDs from each file and as Gillespie mentioned it's all read as one element

Comment: Wholtextfile() works well for smaller files, but if the file sizes are big its going to be detrimental since every file is put as a single record in the RDD.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [toDebugString](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkConf.html#toDebugString()). Using wholeTextFile will read in the entire content of your file as one element, whereas sc.textfile creates an RDD with each line as an individual element - as described [here](http://www.infoobjects.com/spark-core-sc-textfile-vs-sc-wholetextfiles/).

for example:

```
val file= sc.textFile("/user/user01/whatever.txt").cache()

val wordcount = file.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

wordcount.toDebugString

// res0: String =

// (2) ShuffledRDD[4] at reduceByKey at <console>:23 []

// +-(2) MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at <console>:23 []

//    |  MapPartitionsRDD[2] at flatMap at <console>:23 []

//    |  /user/user01/whatever.txt MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:21 []

//    |  /user/user01/whatever.txt HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at <console>:21 []
```

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately if yo give the textfile a patter i.e. *.txt, it will not show the file name and only the pattern, so the debug String doesn't seem to be really useful.

Comment: Did you call it on the val that you apply transformations on? like wordcount in the above example? that should really provide the information on the source that the lines are loaded from..

Comment: tried it again now with filter and the result is the same : (1) MapPartitionsRDD[2] at filter at xxx.java:69 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at xxx.java:68 []
 |  hdfs://localhost:8020/user/xxxxx/*.txt HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at xxx.java:68 []